# Understanding use of multiple SUMs with LEFT JOINS in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

Using the GROUP BY command, it is possible to LEFT JOIN multiple tables and still get the desired number of rows from the first table.

For example,

```
SELECT b.title 
FROM books `b`
LEFT JOIN orders `o` 
ON o.bookid = b.id 
LEFT JOIN authors `a` 
ON b.authorid = a.id 
GROUP BY b.id
```

However, since behind the scenes MYSQL is doing a cartesian product on the tables, if you include more than one SUM command you get incorrect values based on all the hidden rows. (The problem is [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329525/multiple-left-join-with-sum) fairly well here.)

```
SELECT b.title,SUM(o.id) as sales,SUM(a.id) as authors    
FROM books `b`
LEFT JOIN orders `o` 
ON o.bookid = b.id 
LEFT JOIN authors `a` 
ON b.authorid = a.id 
GROUP BY b.id
```

There are a number of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651172/sum-on-multiple-left-joins) on SO about this, most using sub-queries in the JOINS but I am having trouble applying them to this fairly simple case.

How can you adjust the above so that you get the correct SUMs?

**Edit**

Example

```
books
id|title|authorid
1|Huck Finn|1
2|Tom Sawyer|1
3|Python Cookbook|2

orders
id|bookid
1|1
2|1
3|2
4|2
5|3
6|3

authors
id|author
1|Twain
2|Beazley
2|Jones
```

The "correct answer" for total # of authors of the Python Cookbook is 2. However, because there are two joins and the overall dataset is expanded by the join on number of orders, SUM(a.id) will be 4.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "...correct SUMs"? Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: see the example above

Comment: What a bad idea to call it `authors.id` when it is **not** the table's ID. This is a bad data model. You should have an authors table with unique authors and a bridge table to represent the m:n relation between books and authors instead.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Please don't post invalid code as description, it doesn't mean anything. Use words to explain output as a function of input.

Comment: This seems likely to be a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate sums over appropriate rows and/or sum a case statement picking rows; join on common unique column sets. Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think that your query would work like you eexspected.

Assume one book could have **3** authors.

**For Authors**:

So  you would have **three rows** for that book in your books table,each one for every Author.

So a

```
SUM(b.authorid)
```

gives you the correct answer in your case.

For **Orders**:

you must use a subselect like

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(id) o_sum,bookid  FROM orders GROUP BY bookid) `o` 
ON o.bookid = b.id
```

You should really reconsider your approach with books and authors.

Comment: Thanks you. That did the job.

Comment: @zztop: But this is the only wrong answer. Your only mistake is that you are using `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

Comment: I'm sorry Thorsten, I didn't see your answer until I'd already marked this correct having gotten it to work and refreshed the page. You are right that given the sample data I used above SUM would not work. In the actual data there are a lot of other columns including quantity which is what I summed.

Comment: @zztop: This wasn't about my answer. forpas posted their answer much earlier telling you that you are mistakenly using `SUM` and that a way to deal with duplicates are distinct counts. But okay, your example was wrong hence and it's actually other columns you are summing up. Such can easily happen when trying to simplify a query for stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that by joining multiple tables you would not get the expected results.
But in this case you should use `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()` and count the distinct orders or authors.
Also by your design you should count the names of the authors and not the `id`s of the table `authors`:

```
SELECT b.title, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) as sales,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.author) as authors    
FROM books `b`
LEFT JOIN orders `o` ON o.bookid = b.id 
LEFT JOIN authors `a` ON b.authorid = a.id 
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/egFetFd1mWqvYjoqcyKeBq/0).
Results:

```
| title           | sales | authors |
| --------------- | ----- | ------- |
| Huck Finn       | 2     | 1       |
| Tom Sawyer      | 2     | 1       |
| Python Cookbook | 2     | 2       |
```

Comment: Point well taken about Count.

Comment: I just hope that you will not actually use SUM() and a.id to count.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with separate aggregates, it is good style to aggregate before joining.

Your data model is horribly confusing, making it look like a book is written by one author only (referenced by `books.authorid`), while this "ID" is not an author's ID at all.

Your main problem is: **You don't count!** We count with `COUNT`. But you are mistakenly adding up ID values with `SUM`.

Here is a proper query, where I am aggregating before joining and using alias names to fight confusion and thus enhance the query's readability and maintainability.

```
SELECT
  b.title,
  COALESCE(o.order_count, 0) AS sales,
  COALESCE(a.author_count, 0) AS authors
FROM (SELECT title, id AS book_id, authorid AS author_group_id FROM books) b
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id as author_group_id, COUNT(*) as author_count
  FROM authors
  GROUP BY id
) a ON a.author_group_id = b.author_group_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT bookid AS book_id, COUNT(*) as order_count
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY bookid
) o ON o.book_id = b.book_id
ORDER BY b.title;
```